# Catch SIGINT in parent but kills child anyway

Tags: node.js, child-process, sigint

I have a architecture with one parent that spawns tow childs (one in c++ the other in python). The parent spawns with the following class :

```
export class subProcess {
    protected cmd: string;
    protected args: string[];
    protected process: child.ChildProcess;

    constructor(cmd: string, args: string[]) {
        this.cmd     = cmd;
        this.args    = args;
        this.process = null;
    }

    spawn(): void {
        this.process = child.spawn(this.cmd, this.args);

        const rlout = readline.createInterface({
            input: this.process.stdout,
        });
        rlout.on('line', line => this.logger.info(line));

        const rlerr = readline.createInterface({
            input: this.process.stderr,
        });
        rlerr.on('line', line => this.logger.error(line));

        this.process.on('exit', (code: number) => {
            this.logger.info(`exit code: ${code}`);
        });
    }
```

When I interrupt the parent whith a Ctrl-C, signal `SIGINT` is caugth in the parent process to be able to first disconnect and kill the childs gracefully :

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    this.bus.disconnect();
});
```

`disconnect` is a function that sends an `"exit_process"` command to the childs via ZeroMQ. This command works perfectly fine in normal behavior. But the problem is that when I press Ctrl-C, the `SIGINT` is caugth by the Parent and it executes `disconnect` function (as expected) but it seems that it also propagate `SIGINT` to the childs. Indeed, the `"exit_process"` command sent via ZeroMQ reaches it's timeout (which means that the childs have never received/answered) whereas the childs emit a returned code via the `exit` event.

The point is that I can't detache and/or unref the childs, or manage signals in childs, for project reasons. And I expected the parent to catch the `SIGINT` whithout propagating it to the childs.

One more point, I tried to add the following in `subProcess` class, but it did not work :

```
this.process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    console.log('SIGINT received. Do nothing');
});
```

Comment: `SIGINT` is sent to the entire process group. See [this nodejs issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/18600) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface#Controlling_terminals_and_process_groups).

Comment: So the `this.process.on('SIGINT', () => { console.log(...)});`  in `subProcess` class should be caugth, isn't it ? But obviously it seems that it is not the case.
Anyway, is it sends via child's stdin or another way ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `SIGINT` is being passed to the entire process group — see [this section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface#Controlling_terminals_and_process_groups). However, you're probably not seeing any output because of how the child process pipes are established.

When spawning a new child process, you can provide [`stdio` options](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio):

```
this.process = child.spawn(this.cmd, this.args, {stdio: 'inherit'});
```

The above causes the parent's `process.stdin`, `process.stdout`, `process.stderr` to be inherited by the child process. If you use this approach, you will see that your child is receiving the `SIGINT`.

The default behaviour is to create [separate streams](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_stdio), which is why you are not seeing your `console.log`. You could also listen to the child's stdout stream:

```
this.process.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));
```